# variable length c array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, variables

I am using objective c to create a struct holding a variable length array. I know you can create an array of length n like so:

```
double array[n];
```

And i also believe in c++ you can declare:

```
vector<double> array;
```

where you do not have to declare the array length. Is there any way to do something similar in objective c? I am using ARC.

Thanks in advance, Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create an NSMutableArray like-

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];

[myArray addObject:....];// Add as many object as you want.
```

You just need to take care of one thing while creating variable length array, don't add nil as object, as nil is just to signify the end of the variable-length argument list.

EDIT - 
Might be following will help you -
In this way you can define objective c data types in struct-

```
typedef struct{ 
    int numInputs; 
    __unsafe_unretained NSMutableArray *array;
} Pin;
```

Comment: Thanks but you cannot have an NSMutableArray in a struct can you? - EDIT: im using ARC

Comment: typedef struct{
    int numInputs;
    double vecWeight[99];
    
} Pin;

Comment: You can't have a variable length array in a struct. You can either use a custom class instead of a struct or use a pointer to a heap-allocated array in your struct. I.e. 'double* vecWeight;` and, later, `struct Pin pin; pin.vecWeight = malloc(sizeof(double) * count);`.